# Social media platform for creating, sharing and discovering short music videos (alternative to TikTok)

Tags: android, video, music

[Tik Tok (formerly known as musical.ly)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TikTok) is a social media platform for creating, sharing and discovering short music videos, think Karaoke for the digital age. The app musical.ly was used by young people as an outlet to express themselves through singing, dancing, comedy, and lip-syncing.

**"Tik Tok"** was recently banned in India.

What are some alternatives for **"Tik tok"**?

Answer (score 0):

The best ones are likely about to get here a little later this year, namely:

1. [YouTube's Shorts](https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/1/21203451/youtube-tiktok-competitor-shorts-music-google-report)
2. [Instagram Reels](https://techcrunch.com/2020/06/24/instagram-expands-its-tiktok-clone-reels-to-new-markets/), which is already being tested in Brazil.

For now though, you have [byte](https://byte.co/), which is made by the same people who made Vine that heavily inspired Musical.ly/Tiktok. This is already out, but it's much more limited than TikTok. It's slowly adding features, but doesn't have the same feel (at least not yet).

Otherwise, you can temporarily use "Lasso", which is by Facebook, but will be removed completely soon, ahead of Reels being released (since Facebook owns Instagram).

"Likee" has a lot of the same features as TikTok, and it's another option, but it comes across a lot more spammy, and "Triller" focuses on the music aspect that TikTok covers.

There are loads of other copycats, but if you search for anything I put in quotation marks in your App store of choice you'll find a temporary option if its more for the general feel of TikTok you are looking for, and then I'd personally bet more on Reels when that is available, for reaching a greater platform of users.